# Azure App Service doesn't run after upgrading to DotNet Core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

After the release of DotNet Core 2.2 I upgraded my Solution to the new version but when I deploy it to my Azure App Service, it no longer runs. It simply gives the following error:
`The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`

My `.csproj` file looks like this in case you'd need it:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.0.2105168" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DAL\DAL.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Model\Models.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\userPictures\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: On the Azure Portal, go to the App Service > Console.  Type `dotnet --list-runtimes` and see whether 2.2 is there.  If yes, `cd ..\..\LogFiles` and `type eventlog.xml` - the last few lines should show you what it's really struggling with.

Comment: There is also issue registered on GitHub with workaround:

https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2125#issuecomment-446103571

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that asp.net core 2.2 updates have not fully rolled out to all regions for Azure App Services.  See:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/12/04/asp-net-core-2-2-available-today/

They say it will be rolled out over the coming weeks and finished by the end of December.

It seems there is some sort of workaround, although I don't know the specifics:
https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.2/2.2-known-issues.md

Comment: Would it be too much to ask for Microsoft to keep NuGet packages in prerelease until the SDK version they depend on is actually supported?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that nuget updated `web.config` by changing `AspNetCoreHosting` to `AspNetCoreHostingV2`. I reverted to `AspNetCoreHosting` and the app came straight back online. Looks like this will be fixed by end of the year according to links in answer from @Dan.

for the record I'm using `net472` not `netcoreapp2.2`